OpenCV issue with including lib in CMake (Clion)
I have this CMake file in my project:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.28)
project(AICS)
include_directories(include)
include_directories(src)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(OpenCV_DIR "C:/opencv/build")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )

add_executable(AICS main.cpp
        src/MyScreen.cpp
        include/MyScreen.h
        include/Scripts.h
        src/Scripts.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

include_directories("C:/opencv/build/include")

So I can't build my project with this message :
CMake Warning at C:/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake:190 (message):
  Found OpenCV Windows Pack but it has no binaries compatible with your
  configuration.

  You should manually point CMake variable OpenCV_DIR to your build of OpenCV
  library.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/opencv/build/OpenCVConfig.cmake

  but it set OpenCV_FOUND to FALSE so package "OpenCV" is considered to be
  NOT FOUND.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!

I have no ideas, what is a root of this problem.
I have tried a few off internet adviсees:

add line : set(OpenCV_FOUND 1)
zero results
use different versions of opencv
delete line with "find_package". After that I had build my project, but when I run it, it falls with problem about "undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'" with all of opencv-types (but I haven't got any compile problems).
delete CMakeCache.txt file, same empty effect.


What exactly do you have under C:/opencv/build? Do you have OpenCV installation here? Or did you just build OpenCV without installing it?

Are you sure that the binaries in:  C:/opencv/build are compatible with the compiler and bit level that you are currently using. You can't mix MinGW and msvc or mix 32 and 64 bit.

add line : set(OpenCV_FOUND 1) zero results Where ever you found this advice avoid. It's terrible advice that couldn't possibly solve the problem.

@Tsyvarev I think, I installed lib. As I know, I download pre-build version.

@drescherjm I use MinGW only, and 64bit, I am confident, that I didn't mix anything) but maybe I'm checking in the wrong place. And I know that last advice about setting OpenCV_FOUND is the worst advice , but I'm on tilt )

I'll try to build lib by myself

For MinGW I recommend using msys2 to install MInGW and then use pacman to install opencv. This way you are guaranteed to get the correct binaries for your compiler and its a lot easier. I picked the ucrt64 package because ucrt is recommended by msys2.

I have Windows 11, can msys2 cause a problem with it? Anyway, thanks, I'll try it.

I have Windows 11, can msys2 cause a problem with it? No, msys2 is the best and most convenient way to get a working MinGW. I use it with win11.
